# Apache Beam: How to read from multiple Kafka topics with different messages schemes

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam KafkaIO as a source of my pipeline.

I need to read from two Kafka topics topic1 and topic2 and than join this inputs as one to subsequent transformations.

The problem is topic1 and topic2 contain messages with incompatible schemes which when I will read I will map message from each topic to the same scheme.

So the pipeline I'm going for is looking something like this:

```
<read topic1>       <read topic2>     
     |                   |
<map to Foo>        <map to Foo>
     |                   |
      \                 /
<use same subsequent transforms on Foo>
```

One way I found to just solve this is to subscribe to multiple topics at once using `withTopics(...)` and than determine on general `KafkaRecord<K,V>` from which topic the message is came from and than perform a mapping for it.

This looks a bit clumsy ? Is there a proper way to do it in Apache Beam ?